# How can one send a Ctrl-Break to a running Linux process?

Tags: java, linux, kill, jvm-arguments

I am debugging a memory leak in an application running on Sun's JDK 1.4.2_18.  It appears that this version supports the command line param -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak which supposedly causes the JVM to dump heap when it encounters a control-break.  How does one send this to a background process on a Linux box?  It appears that kill signals are the way this ought to work, but I kill -l doesn't report anything that is obviously a Ctrl-Break, at least on my Ubuntu box.

Update: I tested Kill -3 with Sun JDK 1.4.2_18 (_14 was the first to dump heap this way), and it worked.  A heap dump file was created, and the process was still running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

kill -QUIT might do it (it will generate a thread dump which is generated by ctrl-break on windows.  I haven't tried it with the heap dump option though).

Comment: I don't have a linux box with a jvm that supports the -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak option so can't test this (and I've never actually done it so can't vouch that it works).

Comment: I'd much rather see a suggestion of "kill -QUIT" than "kill -3", even though they're equivalent.

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html, SIGQUIT produces a core dump, so I think Ctrl-Break would be more like a SIGTERM, i.e. `kill -TERM` in Linux.

Answer (score 18):

Ctrl-\ is the UNIX/Linux equivalent of Windows Ctrl-Break. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT) also tells me that you can also use Ctrl-4 or SysRq on the Linux virtual console (I guess you'd need something weird for a normal terminal emulator to pass representations of those key presses (over ssh/telnet)).

Comment: Yes, usually the terminal is bound for C-\ to send SIGQUIT.  This is configurable with `stty quit`, and I'm not sure if it's the default on all systems.

Comment: @ephemient it's not always, but even exotic terminals tend to use that. My IBM 3161 does, for example. http://i.imgur.com/6DejIxY.jpg

Comment: A [similar topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45646/how-do-i-exit-or-cancel-a-bad-bash-command)  has been opened and it helped me a lot, for example "Ctrl+Z".

Comment: According to https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html, SIGQUIT produces a core dump, so I think Ctrl-Break would be more like a SIGTERM, i.e. `kill -TERM` in Linux.