# Confused about getchar function and EOF

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> The problem is distinguishing the end of input from valid data. The
> solution is that getchar returns a distinctive value when there is no
> more input, a value that cannot be confused with any real character.
> This value is called EOF, for ``end of file''. We must declare c to be
> a type big enough to hold any value that getchar returns. We can't use
> char since c must be big enough to hold EOF in addition to any
> possible char. Therefore we use int.

From 'The C Programming Language' book. I have three questions.
Firstly, why do I get the output `^\Quit (core dumped)` when I press the keys `ctrl` and `4` simultaneously while the above program runs? I'm using a GNU/Linux machine.

Secondly, I wrote a program like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("The part before EOF\n");
    putchar(EOF);
    printf("The part after EOF\n");
}
```

Then compiled this as 'eof.out' and changed `int c = getchar();` in the program from the book into `char c = getchar();`, saved it and then compiler the program as 'copy.out'.
When I run the command `./eof.out | ./copy.out` in the terminal the output I get is :

```
The part before EOF
```

Meaning the program 'copy.out' worked correctly since it didn't print the second printf but the passage above from the book indicates that there should've been some kind of failure since I changed the `int` into `char` so what happened?

Thirdly, when I change the `char c = getchar();` into `double c = getchar();` and run the command `./eof.out | ./copy.out` the output I get is :

```
The part before EOF
�The part after EOF
```

Why didn't `putchar(EOF);` stop copy.out ? Doesn't a `double` have more bytes than both `int` and `char`? what is happening?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850163/how-can-one-send-a-ctrl-break-to-a-running-linux-process) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226327/what-does-ctrl4-and-ctrl-do-in-bash) regarding Ctrl + 4. It's basically equivalent to Ctrl + Break in Windows.

Comment: `putchar(EOF)` writes a single byte, which is (almost certainly, but may vary depending on platform) 0xff.  `getchar` reads that byte as the integer 255, and `double y = getchar()` thus assigned the value 255 to y.  But 255 != EOF.

Comment: Re “the passage above from the book indicates that there should've been some kind of failure since I changed the `int` into `char`”: The passage from the book does not say there should be some kind of failure. It says `EOF` is “a value that cannot be confused with any real character”; it does not say you cannot convert `EOF` to a `char`. If your C implementation uses an unsigned `char` type, the conversion wraps the value modulo 2^N, where N is the number of bits in a `char`, usually eight, so modulo 256. For example, −1 maps to 255…

Comment: … If your C implementation uses a signed `char`, the conversion is implementation-defined.

Comment: ASCII code points range 0..127. On most (all?) platforms `char` can hold values -128..127. On most (all?) platforms EOF is defined as -1. So, `char` will work just fine in your program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the book is technically wrong if you take its claim out of context, or if you interpret "cannot" as precluding programmer error.  But when that claim is understood as a statement about the behavior of `getchar()`, it is absolutely correct.  If called when there is in fact a character available to return, `getchar()` / `getc()` / `fgetc()` return that character *as an `unsigned char`* (converted to `int`), whereas `EOF` is guaranteed to expand to a negative integer.  The former is always distinguishable from the latter.

Comment: Your three questions are not really related to each other, so they should probably be in separate posts.  The first one in particular is about your operating system's terminal interface and doesn't have anything to do with the C programming language itself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: This was discussed on Stack Overflow years ago. In common C implementations, `EOF` cannot be confused with a character return from `getchar`. But if `char` and `int` are the same width, e.g., both 16 bits, the `unsigned char` that `getchar` returns is automatically converted to its `int` return type, so 65535 would be converted to −1 (assuming wrapping), and it would not be possible to distinguish the character 65535 from the `EOF` value solely by the `getchar` return value. (Testing `feof` could do it.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860943/can-sizeofint-ever-be-1-on-a-hosted-implementation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134054/what-is-the-output-of-fgetc-under-the-special-case-where-int-width-char-bit).

Comment: Acknowledged, @EricPostpischil.  I do think that this is a largely a theoretical possibility, not a practical one, because even if `char` is the same size as `int` on some implementation -- as driven, most likely, by the target architecture -- that implementation does not need to recognize *characters* corresponding to all values in the range of type `char`.  Indeed, this issue is a good reason for such an implementation not to do.  But you're right, in principle, it could happen.

Comment: `double c = getchar();` - what madness is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getchar` and `putchar` work with `unsigned char` values, not `char` values, so declaring `c` to be the `char` type causes a valid character 255 to be confused with `EOF`.

To simplify explanation, this answer assumes a common C implementation, except where stated: `char` is signed and eight bits, `EOF` is −1, and conversions to signed integer types modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>, where *w* is the width of the type, in bits. The C standard permits some variations here, but these assumptions are typical in common C implementations and match the behavior reported in the question.

Consider this code for `eof.c` from the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("The part before EOF\n");
    putchar(EOF);
    printf("The part after EOF\n");
}
```

When this program executes `putchar(EOF)`, what happens is:

- `putchar` converts `EOF` to `unsigned char`. This is specified in C 2018 7.21.7.3 (by way of 7.21.7.7 and 7.21.7.8).
- Converting −1 to `unsigned char` yields 255, because conversion to an unsigned eight-bit integer type wraps modulo 256, and −1 + 256 = 255.
- The character code 255 is written to standard output.

> … changed `int c = getchar();` in the program from the book into `char c = getchar();`, saved it and then compiler the program as 'copy.out'.
> When I run the command `./eof.out | ./copy.out` in the terminal the output I get is :
>
> ```
> The part before EOF
> ```

With `c = getchar();`, what happens when byte 255 is read and `c = getchar()` is evaluated is:

- `getchar` returns 255. Note that it the character code as an `unsigned char` value, per C 2018 7.21.7.1 (by way of 7.21.7.5 and 7.21.7.6).
- To assign 255 to `c`, 255 is converted to the `char` type. Per the assumption above, this wraps modulo 256, producing −1.

−1 is the value of `EOF`, so `c != EOF` is false, so the loop ends, and the program exits.

> Why didn't `putchar(EOF)`; stop copy.out ? Doesn't a `double` have more bytes than both `int` and `char`? what is happening?

With `double c`, the value assigned to `c` is the value returned from `getchar`; there is no change due to the destination type being unable to represent all the values `getchar` returns. When `getchar` returns the valid character code 255, `c` is set to 255, and the loop continues. When `getchar` returns the code −1 for end-of-file, `c` is set to −1, and the loop exits.

> … the book indicates that there should've been some kind of failure since I changed the `int` into `char`…

The passage from the book does not say there should be some kind of failure. It says `EOF` is “a value that cannot be confused with any real character”; it does not say you cannot convert `EOF` to a `char`. If your C implementation uses an `unsigned char` type, the conversion wraps the value modulo 2<sup>*w*</sup>, where *w* is the number of bits in a `char`, usually eight, so modulo 256. For example, −1 maps to 255. If your C implementation uses a signed `char`, the conversion is implementation-defined. So your `eof.c` program does not output an end-of-file indication when `putchar(EOF)` is evaluated. Instead, it outputs the character code 255.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I missed that part...